# HQL - unusual queries

Tags: hibernate, hql, northwind

Using [Northwind database](http://merc.tv/img/fig/Northwind_mdb_physical.gif) I would like to make queries like

- Number of orders from each Customer.Country
- What is the sum of OrderDetails.UnitPrice for every day of week
- Average time from Order.RequiredDate to Order.ShippedDate each year
- ... more queries like these

I have to use hibernate to obtain the result, but I have strong feeling that it is pointless. 
Now I use `createSQLQuery()` because I can easily get result using SQL.

But how to do this using `HQL`? Could you please give me any example? 
I think using `HQL` isn't exactly the most resonable, but I would like to know how it can be done.

[Edit]

For example, can query:

`select avg(DATEDIFF(ShippedDate, OrderDate)), year(ShippedDate) from orders group by year(ShippedDate)`

be translated to `HQL`? or Should I get all Orders first and calculate result myself in my application?

or

`select CompanyName, year(ShippedDate), sum(UnitPrice)/sum(Quantity) from shippers
inner join orders on ShipperID = ShipVia
inner join orderdetails on orderdetails.OrderID = orders.OrderID
group by CompanyName, year(ShippedDate)`

If I don't ask for set of object like Order or Shipper, can I use `HQL`?

I've seen a lot of tutorials, but they all refer to "objective oriented" queries. Could you please show me the way to translate to `HQL` these "unusual" queries?

Comment: Something to be aware of, is that SQLquery makes the application database dependent, HQL is more reasonable than using SQLqueries...
And criterion offers you more readable solutions for dinamic queries, dont be afraid of using those tools when needed. Your question sounds a bit general to me, since you are not providing any start point from your knowledge, most ansewers would be directing you to tutorials.

Comment: @Ziul I've edited my question. I know SQL quite well, but I am new to HQL and I tried only basic examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are these "unusual" queries?  These are exactly the kinds of queries that show why RDBMS is still around.  Unfortunately you do not show your mappings, so I will make a few assumptions...  Looking at some of your bullets:

First, Number of orders from each Customer.Country.  I will assume you have mapped Order->Customer as a `@ManyToOne` association

```
List results = session.createQuery( "select c.country, count(o.id) from Order o join o.customer c" ).list();
Object[] result = (Object[]) results.get( 0 );
print( "Country : " + result[0] );
print( "Number of Orders : " + result[1] );
```

or how about assuming a wrapper (OO!) for the results:

```
List results = session.createQuery( "select new CountryOrderCount( c.country, count(o.id) ) from Order o join o.customer c" ).list();
CountryOrderCount result = (CountryOrderCount) results.get( 0 );
print( "Country : " + result.getCountry() );
print( "Number of Orders : " + result.getOrderCount() );
```

What is the sum of OrderDetails.UnitPrice for every day of week.  I will assume you have OrderDetails->Order mapped and that "day of the week" refers to Order.OrderDate:

```
List results = session.createQuery( "select dayOfWeek(o.orderDate), sum(od.unitPrice) from OrderDetails od join od.order o group by dayOfWeek(o.orderDate)" ).list();
...
```

One thing to note about the above is the use of a function.  This might translate directly into a database function, but is mapped through function templates mapped with the Hibernate Dialect.  For additional info, see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/function/package-summary.html or http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#portability-functions

Comment: By "unusal" I mean I've never seen queries like these in HQL tutorials for beginners (but they are common in SQL tutorials), because goal isn't to obtain set of object (like Shippers or Customers). Thank you!